# sending php array with POST android

Tags: php, android, arrays, post, http-post

I want to send a php array via POST from android to php server and i have this code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity dades = new StringEntity(data);
httppost.setEntity(dades);

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
return resEntity.getContent();
```

I think that the php array may be can go in
`StringEntity dades = new StringEntity(data);`
(data is the php array). Can anyone help me?

Comment: I normally do it this way http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: @jsaye: that qualifies as answer, put the code, some explanation the link down to get some rep

Comment: @konsolenfreddy: thanks for your advice, I'm really new here and sometimes I don't know what to do

Comment: @jsaye: No worries, good find though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    //you can add all the parameters your php needs in the BasicNameValuePair. 
    //The first parameter refers to the name in the php field for example
    // $id=$_POST['id']; the second parameter is the value.
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}}
```

The code above will send an array like this:
`[id=12345, stringdata=AndDev is Cool!]`

If you want a bidimentional array you should do this

```
Bundle b= new Bundle();
b.putString("id", "12345");
b.putString("stringdata", "Android is Cool");
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("info", b.toString()));
```

This will create an array containing an array:

```
[info=Bundle[{id=12345, stringdata=Android is Cool}]]
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/533566/Android/Mobile/sending-array-namevaluepairs-http-post here is the solution!!

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","red"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","white"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","black"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","brown"));
```

where colour is your array tag. Just use `[]` after your array tag and put value. Eg. if your array tag name is `colour` then use it like `colour[]` and put value in loop.

Comment: i had 5 Arraylist id,name,address etc then how can i add this all value in sigle List or array?