# android how can i send array with 1key in POST request

Tags: android, arrays, post

Hello i am new to android , i am trying to send array of string ( contain episode Titles) to server with just 1 key ( which will be called items ) ,i tried to use

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items", "EpTitle1"));
```

but it takes just 1 key for 1 value string not array of string , i want that value to be array ,i found [sending php array with POST android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117532/sending-php-array-with-post-android) ,but in his example b.toString(); only send className not my array . any hint will be appreciated .Thanks

Comment: Hola. What did you do on php side to receive the array and use it?

Comment: @NamikazeMinato hello ,sorry to disappoint you but I am only working in android and do not know php :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a wild guess: Does this work (assuming arrayOfValues is a String array containing your items)?

```
for(String value: arrayOfValues){
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items[]",value));
}
```

This is the way you would send an array of data in HTML to a PHP-server.