# Post ArrayList to php server from Android

Tags: android, webserver, postdata

I have seen couple of examples which takes form data to php server, but I don't see any example for sending arrayList of values to php server. Could anyone help me out ? I know how to do this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12348"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "wassup"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Plz help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","red"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","white"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","black"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colours[]","brown"));
```

where colour is your array tag. Just user `[]` after your array tag and put value. Eg. if your array tag name is `colour` then use it like `colour[]` and put value in loop.

Here is the link : [Orignal Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117532/sending-php-array-with-post-android/14724453#14724453)

Comment: How would I receive the same in Php webserver ?

Comment: For that you have to ask a separate question as I don't know about PHP. And if this answer solves your problem then please mark it as Accepted Answer