# sending array with POST android

Tags: android

How to send array with POST like this

```
"survey_pages": [{
    "id": 1,
    "answers": [
        {"question": 4, "answer": true}, 
        {"question": 2, "answer": 1}, 
        {"question": 3, "answer": 1}, 
        {"question": 1, "answer": "2014-03-18T00:01:30"}
    ]
}]
```

Here id my code for sending data:

```
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", mSettings.getString("token", "")));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("survey_pages[id]", _survey_id));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", _page_id));
            int listSize = _q_list.size();
            for (int i = 0; i<listSize; i++) {
                  question = question_list.get(i).id;
                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answers[question]", question));
                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answers[answer]", "true"));
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117532/sending-php-array-with-post-android

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient):

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after creating name value pair you need just these two lines of code

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params ));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```